# A property of co-brouwerian lattices

Tags: lattice-orders

Let $\mathfrak{A}$ is a bounded co-brouwerian lattice.

Let $x\cap a\ne 0$ for some elements of the lattice. Prove (or disprove) that the pseudodifference $a\setminus^{\ast}x\ne a$.

I recall that pseudodifference on co-brouwerian lattices is define by the formula $$a\setminus^{\ast}b=\operatorname{min}\{z\in\mathfrak{A} \,|\, a\subseteq b\cup z\}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I've found a counterexample myself:

Consider the lattice of all filters (including the improper filter) on $\mathbb{R}$, with the order of filters being the reverse of set-theoretic inclusion.

Let $a$ be the principal filter corresponding to the set $\mathbb{R}$. Let $b$ be a non-trivial ultrafilter on $\mathbb{R}$.

Then $a\setminus^{*}b = a$.